# How to disable single mouse click folder opening?

Tags: 10.04, kde, kubuntu

I am using Lucid 10.04 with KDE.

When I single click on any folder in my file browser it is behaving as a folder.

I am not able to select a folder (it always opens the folder). Right now to select I am using keyboard.

How to avoid this situation?

I saw there are some posts on this and they talk about Nvidia in all those. I don't have an NVIDIA graphics card.

Any solution for this?

Comment: Sounds like dolphin options, lets wait for JanC or another kde bod to give the verdict.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For **KDE**

Open the **System Settings** from the Start Menu.Click Keyboard and Mouse Icon
[image]

Now click on Mouse,and then choose **Double-click to open files and folders( select icons on first click)**
[image]
Now single click is disabled..

For **GNOME**

In File Management Preferences,select **Doulble click to open items**.To access File Management Preferences,goto Places-->Computer (or type **nautilus** in terminal)

And then goto Edit menu from there select Preferences..

[image]

Comment: He said he was using KDE, so he's probably not using Nautilus.

Comment: its not workind her in KDE neon wieh de sektop plasma

Answer (score 3):

In newer Plasma versions, the solution above does not longer work.
The setting moved to:
`System Settings > Desktop behaviour > Workspace`

[image: Screenshot of settings]

**Update Sep 2020**:
Seems like it moved again, now it's in
`System Settings > Workspace > General behaviour`
[image: New Screenshot of the above]

Or directly look for it as described in the answer of SL5net.

Comment: seems not working in KDE neon now

Comment: Thanks, put the new path in.

Answer (score 1):

In KDE Plasma 5.16.3 ist's under **System Settings => Desktop Behaviour => Workspace => Double-click to open files and folders**

[Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wVVE.png)

Comment: KDE neon rebased on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

In KDE Neon: type Alt+Space => type "General Behaviour" => Double-click to open files and folders